# node fetch nginx proxy 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, fetch

I was using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) with a nginx proxy to send requests to an api.

This is the way I was sending the requests

```
const request = require('request');

request({
    url: 'https://google.com',
    proxy: 'https://my-proxy.com',
    strictSSL: false,
    tunnel: false,
}, (err, response, body) => {
    console.log(body)
});
```

Everything was working great

Now, as `request` is deprecated I moved to [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and [https-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent)

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

fetch('https://google.com', {
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('https://my-proxy.com'),
    method: 'GET'
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    return response.text()
})
.then(text => {
    console.log(text)
})
```

And in this case the result is

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

On nginx logs side I have

```
client sent invalid request while reading client request line, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: my-proxy.com, request: "CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1"
```

In case of I can resolve it updating my nginx config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip  on;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";

  ssl_dhparam dhparams.pem;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-proxy.com;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-proxy.com;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # for ssl https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name _;

    location / {
      return 403;
    }
  }

}
```

I am using certbot for ssl

Pretty sure the problem comes from `strictSSL` but I can not found how to do it with `node-fetch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed squid proxy.

Really better than nginx for this type of work